# Annihilator for the function $e^x\cos3x$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am looking for the annihilator of $e^x\cos3x$.

I know that for $\cos(\alpha x)+\sin(\alpha x)$ the annihilator is $(D+\alpha)^2$ as the solutions have to be $-\alpha i$ and $\alpha i$ but what if the function is just $\cos$ or $\sin$?

Comment: Try $(D-1)^2+9$

Comment: @s.harp if it was just $cos 3x$ is would have been $D^2+9$? doesnt it given $cos3x+sin3x$?